How to write a FunctionTransformer that outputs a DataFrame with a different number of columns than of the input DataFrame?
Is it possible to use FunctionTransformer to emulate OneHotEncoder? More generally, is it possible to write a FunctionTransformer such that the number of columns in the output DataFrame is different (either lower or higher) than the number of columns in the input DataFrame?

Yes. Did you try?  (It is not possible to recreate OneHotEncoder exactly as a FunctionTransformer because the latter is stateless, but that seems not to be your underlying question.)

@BenReiniger Yes, I tried it unsuccessfully, hence this post. The problem was that the number of incoming columns didn't match the number of outgoing columns.

Can you provide the full error traceback, and the code that generates it (ideally, a [mre], so including some small dataset that reproduces the error)?
